# Reading in excel files - how to read different sheet Names

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a question about how to read different sheetName ( Every time i am shifting sheet to 0 position `XSSFSheet xlSheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);`  )

Right now my code looks like this:

```
public static String ESLDetailsReadExcelWithColumnName(String path, int row, String sheetName, String colName)
        throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    // Load workbook
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    int colcnt = 0;
    **// Load sheet- Here we are loading first sheet only
    XSSFSheet xlSheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);   
    System.out.println(sheet.getSheetName());
    int colNum = xlSheet.getRow(1).getLastCellNum();
    
    for (int j = 0; j <= colNum; j++) {
        // System.out.println(xlSheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).toString());
        if (colName.equalsIgnoreCase(xlSheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).toString())) {
            colcnt = j;
            break;
        }
    }

    return xlSheet.getRow(row).getCell(colcnt).toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the number of sheets and then loop tghrough the sheets, so putting all your code in a loop, with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++)
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);   
    System.out.println(sheet.getSheetName());
    ....
```